# Exclude json file from being bundled in Vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I'm trying to exclude JSON file from being bundled in Vue. I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428145) but it didn't really helped me to do what I want to do.

I created a Vue project from scratch:

```
vue create hello-world
```

and I added an `import` in the `view` file `Home.vue` so now it looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
   <div v-html="message"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import jsonData from '../assets/test.json'
export default {
  name: 'home',
  data () {
    return {
      message: jsonData
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and overall project structure is out of the box and looks like this:

[image]

So, if I'll use `npm run build` it gets packed into `dist\js\app.ab0cf9cb.js` which is expected and I want it to stay separate file in the `dist` folder.

As far as I understand I need to use `externals` [configuration from webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/), which in my case means I need to create a `vue.config.js` and modifying it in the proper way.

I did try a few things with `vue.config.js`, for example:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    externals: {
      jsonData: '../assets/test.json'
    }
  }
}
```

and changing an import to be `import jsonData from 'jsonData'` but no luck

**My question is:**
What exactly I should put into `vue.config.js` to exclude this file? Or, to be more generic, what should I do to exclude this file?

Comment: The problem here is that `import` would no longer work as jsonData is no longer bundled by webpack.You could try Webpack's [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting#dynamic-imports)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on what your specific needs are the simplest solution may be to just put the file in the public folder.

Webpack wont process these, but simply move them to the dist folder maintaining the folder structure. No configuration needed.

```
/public/assets/test.json
```

See more info on static assets https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder

Comment: Is there any other way for me exclude this file from a bundle?

Comment: Perhaps, but based on the information provided, importing a static JSON file, this is the approach I would recommend. Tell me more about your use case, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This solved for me. I had to import it like that: ```import Test from '../public/assets/test.json'```

Comment: when using vite - this doesn't work anymore, according to documentation "Assets in public cannot be imported from JavaScript". Does anybody have another solution?