# Import object js in vue and exclude this file from bundling

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I start with the simple vue.js application. I have icons in base64 format and put all them as object in separately file icons.js. I want to import this object to the file globals.js as globals constant and use this constant in all places where I need icons. BUT, this file does not need to be bundled.

I have files icons.js, globals.js, main.js, App.vue.

icons.js:

```
export const iconsData =
{
  "large": {
    "2": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAAA3CAYAAAD6+O8NAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQB",
    "3": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwE",
   "777": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFgAAAAUCAYAAAAJD/ojAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQB"
  },
  "small": {
    "2": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADsAAAARCAYAAABjEtTjAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2F",
    "3": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADkAAAAqCAYAAAAJWvOwAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2Fy",
    "777": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAC4AAAAqCAYAAADMKGkhAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2",

  }
};
```

globals.js:

```
import { iconsData } from './assets/icons'


export const icons = {
    getIcon: function (iconNumber) {
            if (!iconsData.large[iconNumber]) {
                return "";
            } else {
                return iconsData.large[iconNumber];
            }
    },
    isIcon:function (iconNumber) {
            return iconsData.large[iconNumber];


    }
};
```

In my App.vue :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <div v-for="channel in channels">


      <div class="icon" >

        <img v-if="icons.isIcon(channel.number)" :src="icons.getIcon(channel.number)" >
        <div v-if="!icons.isIcon(channel.number)" class="channel-name">{{channel.name}}</div>

      </div>

        </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

import {icons} from "./globals"


export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {   
  },
  data() {
    return {         
          icons: icons,

        }
  },

}
</script>
```

I tried
1) [Vue.js exclude settings file from being bundled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428145/vue-js-exclude-settings-file-from-being-bundled)  - not work for me

2)[Exclude json file from being bundled in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56695296/exclude-json-file-from-being-bundled-in-vue?noredirect=1&lq=1) from official documentation my file is in assets, but if I put absolutely path in global.js 
    import { iconsData } from '/assets/icons' - application not compiled. 
Maybe this not right - import icons as const global? What I can do to leave file icons.js separately?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using webpack to build as you've tagged the question with VueCLI. If you don't want the icon data to be bundled, then you need to include such hints to webpack that the icon data should reside in a separate chunk than your app bundle. Something like this should work:

```
const iconsData = import('./assets/icons').then(icons => icons.iconsData);
```

You can also customize what the chunk should be named. Let's say you want it to be named `icons-data`, then you can do this:

```
const iconsData = import(/* webpackChunkName: "icons-data" */ './assets/icons').then(icons => icons.iconsData);
```

Comment: After I change file global.js to 
const iconsData =  import('./assets/icons').then(icons => icons.iconsData); 
received error TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem this way:

1) Delete from icons.js word export

```
const iconsData =
{
  "large": {
    "2": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAAA3CAYAAAD6+O8NAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQB",
    "3": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwE",
   "777": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFgAAAAUCAYAAAAJD/ojAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQB"
  },
  "small": {
    "2": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADsAAAARCAYAAABjEtTjAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2F",
    "3": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADkAAAAqCAYAAAAJWvOwAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2Fy",
    "777": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAC4AAAAqCAYAAADMKGkhAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2",

  }
};
```

2) Delete from globals.js import

```
export const icons = {
    getIcon: function (iconNumber) {
            if (!iconsData.large[iconNumber]) {
                return "";
            } else {
                return iconsData.large[iconNumber];
            }
    },
    isIcon:function (iconNumber) {
            return iconsData.large[iconNumber];


    }
};
```

3) Add to index.html referense to icons.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>Icons</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= BASE_URL %>icons.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but egg doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

4) Copy file icons.js to the public folder and to the src root

How I understand - this way exclude the file from webpack in "old school" way. How to do this with webpack - I do not understand.