# Prevent service-worker.js from being bundled with vite / rollup

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, service-worker, rollup, vite

I have a TypeScript-based Vuejs project compiled and bundled using Vite.

I am trying to configure the build system to compile my custom service worker (src/service-worker.ts) and place the output in dist/service-worker.js. In particular, I don't want it included as part of the application's JS bundle, because it needs to be served at that well-known URL as part of a static website.

The existing structure is like:

```
index.html
public/
 favicon.ico
src/
 service-worker.ts
 main.ts
 /* etc */
```

And I would like the output to be something like:

```
dist/
 index.html
 assets/index.[hash].js
 assets/vendor.[hash].js
 /* ... */
 service-worker.js  # <-- I would like the file emitted here
```

If the service worker didn't need to be transpiled/compiled, I know I could simply [include it in `public/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56695459/925478) and it would be copied to the `dist/` folder unchanged.

I've looked at [vite-plugin-pwa](https://github.com/antfu/vite-plugin-pwa) but that is rather opaque and tied to workbox.

Other related questions relate to situations where people want to [exclude files altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43428145/925478) from their build output, which is not quite what I'm after.

How can I compile a TypeScript file but leave its output unbundled in my dist folder?

Comment: Does the info at https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/1736 help? It sounds like it's a question of dropping down and configuring Rollup directly. Either an IIFE (preferred) or UMD bundle of your `service-worker.ts` should work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can configure the entry point and output locations via [`build.rollupOptions`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#build-rollupoptions) in your Vite config:

1. Add an entry point for the `service-worker.ts` file (via [`build.rollupOptions.input`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#input)).
2. Add a formatter for output filenames that puts the service worker file in the root of the output directory (via [`build.rollupOptions.output.entryFilenames`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputentryfilenames)).

```js
// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        // the default entry point
        app: './index.html',

        // 1️⃣
        'service-worker': './src/service-worker.ts',
      },
      output: {
        // 2️⃣
        entryFileNames: assetInfo => {
          return assetInfo.name === 'service-worker'
             ? '[name].js'                  // put service worker in root
             : 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js' // others in `assets/js/`
        }
      },
    },
  },
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-separate-entry-for-service-worker-eym7xf?file=vite.config.ts)