# Can't get Vite to build app and js file into the same dist

Tags: vue.js, build, service-worker, vite, rollup

I'm having trouble configuring `vite.config.js` so that I can have both my Vue app and a service worker file live in the dist folder. My service worker was working with webpack previously but I've just upgraded to Vite and I'm having trouble configuring the build. My goal is to have my dist folder look like:

```
dist
 |- index.html
 |- sw.js
 |- assets
  |- app.[hash].js
```

I tried various different configurations but none of them have worked:

1. An approach that is [recommended by Workbox](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/using-workbox-without-precaching/#rollup). It seems like this doesn't work because of what is mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2039#issuecomment-779356090).
2. After reading that comment I tried to separate the logic out into a separate file (`vite-sw.config.js`) and running `vite build -c vite-sw.config.js`. This successfully generated the file I wanted but I couldn't figure out how to get that file mixed in with the original build. Is there a way to combine `vite build` and `vite build -c vite-sw.config.js` so that they both output to the same `dist` directory without overriding each other?
3. I found this [alternative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71358283/11150269) which successfully created the folder structure I wanted in dist but I was unable to adjust the `format` of the service worker file so I got `Cannot use import statement outside a module (at sw.js:1:1)` in the browser. Is there some way to use this method and somehow configure the format of the service worker file?

Any other ideas? I've been pretty stuck on this for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your configuration like this:

```
export default defineConfig({

  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
        output:
        {
            format: 'es',
            strict: false,
            entryFileNames: "[name].js",
            dir: 'dist/'
        }
     }
  },
.
.
.
```

});

Comment: Had similar problem as OP but with React app and this helped.